# Check a radio button from another element using jquery

Tags: jquery, html

Is it possible to check a radio button by clicking on an unrelated html element ie. a button, list-item or anchor?

I am fairly new to jquery and am not sure if i am taking the right apporach

Here is my HTML

```
<ul>
<li>
    <a href="#p1">
    </a>
</li>
<li>
    <a href="#p2">
    </a>
</li>
<li>
    <a href="#p3">
    </a>
</li>
```

```
<ul class="package">
<li>
    <input type="radio" name="Package1" id="Package1" value="Package 1">
    <label for="Package1"> package 1</label>
</li>
<li>
    <input type="radio" name="Package2" id="Package2" value="Package 2">
    <label for="Package2"> package 2</label>
</li>
<li>
    <input type="radio" name="Package3" id="Package3" value="Package 3">
    <label for="Package3"> package 3</label>
</li>
```

and jquery

```
 <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#p1").click(function () {
            $('input:radio[name=Package1]').prop('checked', true);
            $('input:radio[name=Package2]').prop('checked', false);
            $('input:radio[name=Package3]').prop('checked', false);
        });

        $("#p2").click(function () {
            $('input:radio[name=Package2]').prop('checked', true);
            $('input:radio[name=Package1]').prop('checked', false);
            $('input:radio[name=Package3]').prop('checked', false);
        });
        $("#p3").click(function () {
            $('input:radio[name=Package3]').prop('checked', true);
            $('input:radio[name=Package1]').prop('checked', false);
            $('input:radio[name=Package2]').prop('checked', false);
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: first: use $(selector).on (eventType, func) its a newer and nicer approach for event binding. And well...yes I think that might work... did u tried it at least before u ask this question ^^ ?

Comment: You are using `id selector` and you don't have elements with that id.
You should use  `$("a[href=#p1]").click...`  `$("a[href=#p2]").click...` and   `$("a[href=#p3]").click...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The premise works, however you have a few syntax errors. Your lists are missing closing `</ul>` elements and you're selecting by IDs that don't exist. Here's a working example:

```js
$("#p1").click(function() {
  $('input:radio[name=Package1]').prop('checked', true);
  $('input:radio[name=Package2]').prop('checked', false);
  $('input:radio[name=Package3]').prop('checked', false);
});
$("#p2").click(function() {
  $('input:radio[name=Package2]').prop('checked', true);
  $('input:radio[name=Package1]').prop('checked', false);
  $('input:radio[name=Package3]').prop('checked', false);
});
$("#p3").click(function() {
  $('input:radio[name=Package3]').prop('checked', true);
  $('input:radio[name=Package1]').prop('checked', false);
  $('input:radio[name=Package2]').prop('checked', false);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>
    <a href="#p1" id="p1">1
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#p2" id="p2">2
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#p3" id="p3">3
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
<ul class="package">
  <li>
    <input type="radio" name="Package1" id="Package1" value="Package 1">
    <label for="Package1">package 1</label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <input type="radio" name="Package2" id="Package2" value="Package 2">
    <label for="Package2">package 2</label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <input type="radio" name="Package3" id="Package3" value="Package 3">
    <label for="Package3">package 3</label>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

The selector is wrong and your ul it's not closed.

Try to add ids on this hrefs:

```
<ul>
<li>
    <a href="#" id="p1">
    </a>
</li>
<li>
    <a href="#" id="p2">
    </a>
</li>
<li>
    <a href="#" id="p3">
    </a>
</li>
</ul>
```

And it's good use preventDefault() on the function that calls the a href to don't change the url

```
 <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#p1").click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $('input:radio[name=Package1]').prop('checked', true);
            $('input:radio[name=Package2]').prop('checked', false);
            $('input:radio[name=Package3]').prop('checked', false);
        });

        $("#p2").click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $('input:radio[name=Package2]').prop('checked', true);
            $('input:radio[name=Package1]').prop('checked', false);
            $('input:radio[name=Package3]').prop('checked', false);
        });
        $("#p3").click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $('input:radio[name=Package3]').prop('checked', true);
            $('input:radio[name=Package1]').prop('checked', false);
            $('input:radio[name=Package2]').prop('checked', false);
        });
    });
</script>
```

And if you are using the newer versions of Jquery, use .on('click', function() instead .click(function()

;)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working example.

You just need to refer the element correctly either with ID or Class.

```
    <ul>
  <li>
    <a id="p1" href="#p1">Click me</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <button id="p2">Click Me
    </button>
  </li>
</ul>
<ul class="package">
  <li>
    <input type="radio" name="Package1" id="Package1" value="Package 1">
    <label for="Package1"> package 1</label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <input type="radio" name="Package2" id="Package2" value="Package 2">
    <label for="Package2"> package 2</label>
  </li>
</ul>


 $(document).ready(function() {
   $("#p1").click(function() {
     $('input:radio[name=Package1]').prop('checked', true);
     $('input:radio[name=Package2]').prop('checked', false);
     $('input:radio[name=Package3]').prop('checked', false);
   });

   $("#p2").click(function() {
     $('input:radio[name=Package2]').prop('checked', true);
     $('input:radio[name=Package1]').prop('checked', false);
     $('input:radio[name=Package3]').prop('checked', false);
   });
 });
```